# How to fetch record in [slug].js using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working in Reactjs and i am using "nextjs" framework,Right now i am getting data(blog detail) according to slug([slug.js]) but on the right side of page (sidebar) i want to get data of all other
blogs with same category(cat_name),how can i do this ? Here is my current code

```
import Axios from "axios";
import  {useRouter}  from "next/router";
//import LatestBlogs from "../../components/LatestBlogs/LatestBlogs";
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
//import Header from '../../components/Layout/Header'



const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  // const htmlString = {post.description_front};

  const htmlString = post?.description_front
//  console.log({post.});



  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
<header className="inner-header">

            <div className="container">
                <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-lg main-header' >
                <Link href="/">
                    <a classNameName="navbar-brand" href=''> <img src="/img/logo1.png" /> </a></Link>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"><img src="/img/list.svg" /></span>
                    </button>
                </nav>
            </div>
            </header>

            <div className="alfa-img">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-7">
                            <div className="release-time">
                                <img className="mask-img" src={post.image} />
                            </div>
                            <div className="game-re">
                                <h2>{post.title} !</h2>
                                    {post.description}
                                       </div>
                        
                        </div>


                        <div className="col-md-5">
                            <div className="pined">
                                <h3>Pinned</h3>

                            //Following div should be dynamic 
                                <div className="img-content">
                                    <div className="img-pined">
                                        <img className="mask-on" src="/img/Mask Group 11.png" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="alfa-lp">
                                        <h4>Alpha Release Time !</h4>
                                        <p>With the launch of our social media and publications, the only question is, &apos; When will the game be released?&apos;
                                                    MBG plans to release the game in stages and versions such as alpha - first release, beta - second release, release and versions - which will be the final release and then MBG will release the latest updates through release versions.
                                                    Regarding the debut of MBG, the full steps of the game&apos;s release will be announced when the roadmap is released</p>
                                                 <h6 className="post-date post">Posted: 14 oct 22</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
           
</>

  );
};

export default Post;

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
 const { data } = await Axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${params.slug}`);
  const post = data;
  return {
    
    props: {
      post,
    },
  };
};




export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get("http://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/blogs");
  const posts = data.slice(0, 10);
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({ params: { slug: post.slug.toString() } }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};
```

Comment: Fetch the data for the sidebar inside `getStaticProps` too, then pass it down to the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use getStaticProps function two times in same page.

Comment: okay then what is the solution then ?

Comment: OP is not using `getStaticProps` twice in the same page. OP is using `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` which are needed for statically generated dynamic routes.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing different than fetching the post. If there is a REST endpoint for posts with a specific category, it could look like this.

```
export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${params.slug}`);
  const post = data;

  const { catData } = await Axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/${post.cat_name}`);
  const catPosts = catData;
  
  return {
    props: {
      post: post,
      catPosts: catPosts
    },
  };
};
```